# Xcode 7 UITextView weird behavior failing view loading

Tags: crash, uitextview, viewcontroller, xcode7

According to my observation, in XCode 7, if you put a UITextView in storyboard, and if the default text is less than 10 characters, the view controller won't load, and XCode throws no exception either - the app just hangs there.

I found it while migrating one of my XCode 6 project to XCode 7, and spent a lot of time to get there. I also started a clean slate project to confirm this behavior, and hope to put here to see if anybody else can confirm this?

Comment: I don't have a solution but I wanted confirm I'm having the same problem. I  removed parts of the UI one by one until I isolated it to the UITextView.

Comment: Exactly, I did the same thing to dig it out. My current workaround is to put 10 spaces in there for now. I guess I have to release my app with this workaround.

Comment: Wow.  I just spent a few hours narrowing down the problem to a UiTextField and Google led me here.  What a frustrating bug!

Comment: Yep, surprised to see it. Apple should fix this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this same thing, and was going to submit a question before I found this but I do not have the required reputation points to comment on the above question. This most definitely worked on xcode 6.4 with iOS 8 and is a new bug with xcode 7 as well as 7.0.1. This is an issue with both the simulator as well as on device.

iOS bug 22983873 submitted.